# Import parse.com library into Android studio 0.8.2

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm trying to import the Parse-1.5.1.jar file into my project in Android studio following these steps:
- File -> Project structure
- Click on the plus button and click on Import .JAR or .AAR package
- Choose my jar file and then hit finish

But then any command from the parse library is recognized. For example : "Cannot resolve symbol ParseObject" and android studio doesn't propose me to import anything.

I can't find on stackoverflow any instruction for these version of Android studio and Parse.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Today i too started with Parse. All you need to do is:

- **Copy** the parse-1.5.1.Jar file (Ctrl+c) and **paste** it in **app->libs folder**
- Ensure `build.gradle` inside the **app folder** contains this line:  `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

That's it. You just need to click on **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button on the top to rebuild your project. You'll now be ready to use the classes from the Parse Library.

Hope this helps. All the best

Answer (score 4):

Take your Parse-1.8.4.jar file and copy and paste it into your libs folder. 
[image]

Then make sure your manifest has all the correct permissions. Here is some, but there are more permissions than this:
[image]

Make sure you have the parse class that extends Application and calls Prase.initialize in onCreate().

Then go to File -> Project Structure. In the pop-up, select "app" -> "Dependencies" tab -> Click on the plus sign and select "File dependency". Then select your "Parse-1.8.4.jar" file.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly open your project libs file. Download parse example project code from https://www.parse.com/tutorials#android . opy the libs file.Paste them to your project file/libs file.Click File in android studio and then click project structure tab or hit the F4 if its work. And click "app" left side of tab in opened window.Then Dependencies tab. Click "+" on right side. Click File Dependency and click libs and find the Parse.xxx.jar file and click OK and Apply . Tahts it. And you can also take look here https://www.parse.com/tutorials#android.